# How to add a step to electron builder installer in MacOS

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder, pkg-file, electron-packager

I am trying to create a pkg file of my `electron` application using `electron-installer-dmg` and `electron-packager`.

Digging into the documentation of these two (and few other tools), I couldn't find a configuration or solution to add a step in the install process.

To be more clear, when I click on the pkg file, I would like to have a user agreement step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `dmg`, you can simply drop a license file in the build folder. Look [here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Options#user-content-Config-dmg) for more details.

For `pkg`, unfortunately, it is not developed yet. [Here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/1547) is the related issue.